# Sample data and admin not showing in magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

I have successfully install magento on my system. I am using PHP version 7.1.28, Magento CLI version 2.1.17 and window 10. I have attached the success screen. When I run front-end, There is no sample data in it. also when I run admin panel nothing visible for me.
I have suffered a lot but not getting any solution. I am new on magento version 2. Please help me to solve the problem.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noticed we are having some issue in Magento 2 with windows operating system, where it was not able to fetch the directory path correctly. For that, need to apply some core fix. try with below solution it might help you.

**Navigate to below file**

vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php

In function, isPathInDirectories added below line

$realPath = str_replace('\', '/', $realPath);

or refer below code function

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
{
    if (!is_array($directories)) {
        $directories = (array)$directories;
    }
    $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
    $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $realPath); // extra code added
    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
        if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check below links for similar issue.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102671/magento-2-sample-data-installed-but-not-showing
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163145/magento-2-sample-data-not-showing

Basically you should run few basic commands after installation. Have you tried doing that?

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have run these many time. There are lots of js issue. one of them is "The resource from “http://localhost/magento2/mage/bootstrap.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)."

when I see folder structure there is no mage folder in magento2

Comment: @Yogendra, check below link, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152625/magento2-css-was-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosn?rq=1
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162749/magento-2-why-css-was-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch
if these not working then best way is try new installation.

Comment: I think linux is better for programming. I did the same process on linux with php 7.1 and magento 2.1.17 and change folder permission. Now it is working for me

Answer (score 0):

It may be a file permission issue. Make sure you have a right file permissions